# When using 'npm' it requires me to login to github

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js

**Problem** When i try to use `npm` in any way, ex: `npm update` or `npm i package` it immediatly gives me a github login prompt.

**What i tried** using npm with `i`, `install`, and even giving it git directly `git://`. But none worked sadly.

I am new to Node.js. So far (2 weeks), i have been updating, installing and reinstalling dependencies without a problem. Just now this issue occured.

What i was doing before the error occured was nothing special. Just programming. Last thing i used npm for was to install discord.js `npm i discord.js`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you install nodejs/npm? Also, what OS are you using? I think we need a lot more information here to be able to diagnose what's going on.

Comment: Updated my post with more info and screenshots.

Comment: npm install <package name> where <package name> is the name of the package not a file name.  We might be able to offer more assistance if you showed a screen shot of some actual install.  Not sure why you would "npm i"  without a package name - maybe thats a thing, bnut I am not aware of it.

Comment: already tried that. for example lets say i wanna install node-split. i use `npm install node-split`. this gives the same result. login to github. anything i wanna install with `npm i` gives me the github login page. no matter what package. even the `npm update` gives the same issue.

Comment: which node / npm version?  Maybe run npm doctor and post your results?

Comment: updated post with npm-doctor results

Comment: I had this issue trying to import a project, I renamed the package-lock.json to another name, then re-installed "npm install xxx" the packages again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. The problem was very simple but i couldn't figure it out at first.

So what was wrong with my issue here was that i accidently while working on my project changed a value in the "Package.json" file. This is ofcourse not intended. With that, my whole project's 'npm' command was broken where it could't work anymore.

Thank you everyone for your time.

Comment: What do you mean you changed a value in the "Package.json" file?

Comment: I modified the "Package.json" file manually, adding entries and what not, and I think this was the cause of my error.

Comment: It would be more helpful to the SO community if you state exactly what you changed in your "Package.json" file.

Comment: This is a 3 year old post. I do not remember what i changed exactly. But i am sure because i modified the "package.json" manually with wrong letters/symbols, it kind of broke my project. What i did was delete "package.json" and install all dependencies again, which initiated the file again.

Answer (score 30):

to have such a problem, it means your command is wrong. take for example you are trying to install angular cli and you omit the @ symbol login will pop like so

npm install -g angular/cli         // this will trigger login pop-up
npm install -g @angular/cli        // will work fine
so check your command

Comment: This worked for me. I'm very surprised it isn't well documented, would save me hours of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok similar issue happened to me but if figured it out whichever "last" package you tried to install in your project, there must've been a typo or so because the error comes from there
Let's say discord.js
it must've been created something like this in the package.json file:

```
dependencies {
    undefined: "discord.js"
}
```

As for me it was

```
dependencies {
    "undefined": "react-three/drei"
}
```